# Why does 'this' return 'undefined' when referred in an arrow function but doesn't when called on an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects, arrow-functions

I'm working with node.js v6.7.0 and while declaring an object with a reference to 'this' it returns undefined if it's inside an arrow function but when it's inside a regular anonymous function it returns the object itself (which is what I want)

eg

```js
let obj = {
  key: 'val',
  getScopeWithArrow: () => {return this;}, //returns undefined
  getScopeWithAnonymous: function() {return this;} //returns the object properly
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Something's special about the arrow functions, in that way I projected it.

Comment: Google search: [site:stackoverflow.com javascript this undefined in arrow function](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+javascript+this+undefined+in+arrow+function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because arrow functions don't have their own `this`, they *close over* the `this` of the calling context. But non-arrow functions, if they're not bound, take `this` based on *how they're called*. I assume you're calling these functions like this:

```
obj.getScopeWithArrow();
obj.getScopeWithAnonymous();
```

In the first case, again, the arrow function doesn't get its own `this` so it doesn't matter how you're calling it. In the second case, it *does* matter, and calling it like that makes `this` within the call refer to the same object `obj` refers to.

---

Separately: In your example, you must be in strict mode, because `this` can only be `undefined` in strict mode.

Separately 2: With regard to your method names: `this` and "scope" have very, very little to do with one another.

---

Some examples:

```js
function showThis(label, t) {
  if (t === window) {
    console.log(label, "(global object)");
  } else {
    console.log(label, t);
  }
}
// Loose mode by default in a non-module script element
let obj = {
  arrow: () => {
    showThis("arrow says ", this);
  },
  normal: function() {
    showThis("normal says ", this);
  }
};
obj.arrow();  // global object (window on browsers)
obj.normal(); // obj

function foo() {
  // Here, we're in strict mode
  "use strict";
  let obj = {
    arrow: () => {
      showThis("arrow says ", this);
    },
    normal: function() {
      showThis("normal says ", this);
    }
  };
  obj.arrow();  // undefined
  obj.normal(); // obj

}
foo();
```

Comment: Such a nice answer, thank you T.J. for taking your time to explain it up!

Answer (score 0):

According to developer.mozilla.org (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> **No binding of this**
>
> Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own this value (a new object in case of a constructor, undefined in strict mode function calls, the context object if the function is called as an "object method", etc.). This proved to be annoying with an object-oriented style of programming.

**BUT**

If the goal is to avoid writing function, you can avoid using the colon and declare your method with the new ECMA6  object function declaration syntax.

```js
let obj = {
  key: 'val',
  getScopeWithParens() {return this;}, //returns object
  getScopeWithAnonymous: function() {return this;} //returns the object properly
}

console.log(obj.getScopeWithAnonymous());
console.log(obj.getScopeWithParens());
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about that new syntax on ES6, thank you by the way, maybe I should try that